# Printf inserts % at the end of the line

Tags: c, printf

I'm writing a basic program to learn how to use basic input/output in C, and it works just fine. The only problem I have is when it prints, there is a "%" at the end of the string on the terminal. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char name[32];

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Hello, %s", name);

    return 0;

}
```

When I run the program, the output is `Hello, Andrew%`

Any help?

Comment: Working fine in Visual Studio. Which compiler you are using?

Comment: You aren't adding a newline to the end of your output; just out of curiosity, is `%` the prompt character on your system?

Comment: @pranitkothari: Emacs and GCC

Comment: @JohnBode: No, I use zsh with the ">" character

Comment: What is the output if you use `printf("(Hello, %s)", name);`, just curious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's nothing in your code that should explain this behavior. However, it seems likely that if you are running this from a shell, that may be your shell prompt.

Add a newline to your output:

```
printf("Hello, %s\n", name);
```

This should cause the prompt to print on the next line as you probably expected.

Comment: Not my shell prompt, but the newline did it for some reason... , thanks!

Comment: @ahalverson: I'm not a zsh user but it looks like `zsh` does this in order to inform you the previous command didn't include a terminating newline. You can see the same behavior with `echo -n abc`.

Answer (score 4):

The `stdout` stream is line buffered. What this means is the output does not appear on the console until a newline is output or the buffer is full. This may be a cause why you are seeing a `%` on the screen. `'\n'` causes `printf` to print the output immediately on the screen.

Note that if the input string is larger than `31` characters, then `scanf` will overrun the buffer `name` invoking undefined behaviour. This may crash the program due to segfault. You should safeguard against it by providing the maximum field width which should be 1 less than the array length to accommodate for the terminating null byte added by `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// if your not using command line argument, use the below
// signature of main
int main(void) {
    char name[32];

    printf("Enter your name: \n");  // add a newline to output
    scanf("%31s", name);  // -1 for the terminating null byte
    printf("Hello, %s\n", name);  // add a newline to output

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command line `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''` into your zsh shell, that should be enough to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not output a new line - that is your shell prompt character being shown after the specified output. Try `printf("Hello, %s\n", name);`

Answer (score -2):

PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''

add this line to your .zshrc file.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, especially when you post an answer without any explanation